# In Ubuntu browser disappeared out of sight - off the left side of the screen - and couldn't bring it back

Tags: ubuntu, workspace

I was watching a Youtube video in Ubuntu and whatever way I moved the mouse, it caused Firefox to disappear out of sight off of the left side of the page. I tried ALT+TAB to bring it back. Also the ESC key. In the end I had to restart the computer. Surely there's a simple solution here?

Comment: For future ref if your system gets stuck, use CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE to reset your DE, instead of rebooting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu has a concept called workspaces. Workspaces are basically virtual desktops. They help you manage and organize application windows. My guess is you inadvertently moved Firefox to an alternate workspace.

Here is a [video](http://ubuntuclips.org/videos_30.html) showing how to switch between, and use workspaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the default metacity window manager or several others (like my favorite, icewm) you can move a window with the keyboard by pressing Alt+F7 and using the arrow keys.

If the window was uncontrollably jumping off your screen, it's either a bug in Firefox, a buggy addon, or very weird JavaScript on the page itself.

Comment: This still works in Ubuntu Unity 13.04... thx.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+leftmouse+drag works too, but I have had occasions when part of the window is still on screen and it won't budge. When that happens it doesn't show up on any other workspaces either.

You don't need to restart though, you should be able to just kill the process

Answer (score 0):

As w4g3n3r said, it sounds like you've been a "victim" of workspaces.

I found out by accident that scrolling your mouse wheel while the mouse is over the background/wallpaper will switch workspaces.